# how to store a result of for loop into a variable like array

Tags: python

I've used a `for` loop to generate the result.

```
for i in range(len(z)):
    if z[i] > sd:
        result = 1
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
        print(result)
```

but I'm not able to store it into a variable.
any suggestions.

Comment: Why can't you just use `append`? It seems you're already working with a list so I assume you're familiar with their methods

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
In particular, what do you mean that "I'm not able to store it into a variable"?  You control the programming; what do you want for a result, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Don't use `for i in range(len(z))` if you don't really need the indexes. Just use `for e in z` to iterate over the elements directly.

Answer (score 1):

the most pythonic way would be to create a list comprehension with the boolean value converted as integer:

```
results = [int(v > sd) for v in z]
```

(that is if you *really* want integers, otherwise, don't convert and leave the booleans as-is in the list)

```
results = [v > sd for v in z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list like this:

```
results = list()
for i in range(len(z)):
    if z[i] > sd:
        result = 1
        results.append(result)
    else:
        result = 0
print(results)
```

Comment: You need to append in the `else`, or after the whole `if-else` section.